# Javascript - define object with private variables without function

Tags: javascript

Usually, you can create private variables by using `var x` instead of `this.x` in defining function and then you create objects like so: `var o = new SomeClass()`. However, I need something like PHP class with static methods (object with private variables without any further assigning). Same like defining class and then creating the object from it, but directly defining the object, while still maintaining private variables. Is it possible?

---

EDIT:
Normal private variable definition:

```
function SomeClass() {
    var x = '1dg5456awd32tr5';
    this.getX = function() {return private;}
}
var o = new SomeClass();
o.getX();
```

How to save that x variable without using the function?

Comment: Can you be more clear? Try adding some psudo-code to illustrate what you're looking for.

Comment: I did not understand the question either.

Comment: I think the OP wants to construct an object from an object literal, but with private variables. Closures are the solution, I'll write an answer tomorrow if nobody has by then.

Comment: *"How to save that x variable without using the function?"* You can't, hence it being *"private"*. it's only available within that scope, other than by using said function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I have understood correctly your question but you can take advantage of the javascript scope behaviour by creating something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/2R8yY/

```
var Order = (function(){
    var company = 'ACME';
    var klassOrder = function(){};
    klassOrder.getCompany = function(){
        return company;
    }
    return klassOrder;
})();

console.log(Order.getCompany()); // -> ACME
```

Answer (score 1):

Privacy of the local variable scope is not restricted to constructor functions. However, you always need to invoke a function to create a "private" scope - even if that function is not assigned to any identifier.

You seem to be looking for [Immediately-Executed Function Expressions](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) or the [module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html).

```
var o = (function() {
    var x = '1dg5456awd32tr5';
    return {getX: function() {return private;}};
}());
o.getX();
```

Comment: @Ejay: No, OP wants a getter. If you did return `x`, then you could have written just `var o = '1dg5456awd32tr5';` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, in JavaScript functions *are* objects.

Because JavaScript scope is functional, it becomes easy to restrict member variable access by declaring local variables in a function's scope. Most commonly, the [Facade Pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#facadepatternjavascript) or [Module Pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript) are used.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
var SomeClass = (function(myPrivateThingy) {
  var privateInt = myPrivateThingy;
  return function() {
    this.getInt = function() { return privateInt; }
  }
}());

var instance = new SomeClass(99);
// instance.getInt() === 99
```